# Macro to reconstruct receipts from database

Tags: database, vba, excel

I need some help with a database I am trying to create on excel. Currently, I managed to build a system where I paste on to the excel sheet a receipt, then a macro extract certain pieces of information and stores it in another sheet, something like this;

```
BUYER  SELLER  DATE  PRODUCTS  CURRENCY
A      B       123   abc        USD
D      E       456   def        GBP
```

Now, I can search this database using simple filtering. What I would to do now is, once I have filtered and am left with, lets say, 5 entries, I would like those to be reconstructed in another sheet, looking like the receipts do originally e.g

```
123           456
A             D
B             E
USD           GBP
a             d
b             e
c             f
```

I know I need to loop through each row and once in a row, loop through each column to extract the required piece of information(e.g date, products etc).
I have looked around and couldn't find anything.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you share some examples of your 'database' and the receipts?

Comment: good point, done!

Comment: Does it mean that in your products column you can have more products and you want to slit them?

Comment: yeah, but thats not a problem for me because I made another macro that does that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this can help you to start:

```
Sub From_DB()
Dim i As Long
Dim col As Integer
Dim DB_Sheet, Rec_Sheet As Object

Set DB_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
Set Rec_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Receipts")
col = 1
For i = 2 To DB_Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If DB_Sheet.Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
        Rec_Sheet.Cells(1, col) = DB_Sheet.Cells(i, 3)
        Rec_Sheet.Cells(2, col) = DB_Sheet.Cells(i, 1)
        Rec_Sheet.Cells(3, col) = DB_Sheet.Cells(i, 2)
        Rec_Sheet.Cells(4, col) = DB_Sheet.Cells(i, 5)
        Rec_Sheet.Cells(5, col) = DB_Sheet.Cells(i, 4)
    col = col + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```